# Post Path Projection ( trail ) in cocos2d iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i want to create path projection like angry birds. 
When i throw my ball i want to show projection on ball that on this path my ball has thrown.

I have seen a post on stackoverflow and i have implemented it .

```
if(trailtimer % 2 == 0 && isFired)
        {

                CCSprite * dot_Sprite = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithFile:@"whitedot.png"];
                dot_Sprite.position = ccp(b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO,b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);
                dot_Sprite.scale = 0.1;
                [self addChild:dot_Sprite z:2 tag:111];
            }

        }
```

In this code its working fine . but adding multiple sprites will slow my game.
Is there anyother option/way to implement path projection in my game.

[image]

Comment: make sure the sprites are batched

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create the dot like this:

```
CCSprite * dot_Sprite = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"whitedot.png"];
```

and see if it helps.
This will add the dot to the auto release pool and make sure memory is free after usage